# How to assign different colors for each list item in the list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a list view in which I am loading my own layout. I am changing the color of the custom view but its not refleting.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

In your custom layout recognize your root element and set its background color.

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to  create custom adapter, and configure individual views as you like.  Keep in mind, that list views can be recycled for better performance

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to use any two colors then you can use below code into your customAdapter.

```
    private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.LTGRAY, Color.WHITE };
```

And in getView() write

```
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
```

I hope it helps you.